# Show/hide TextBox based on status of RadioButton

Tags: textbox, google-apps-script, radio-button

I would like to show "txtElementID" when the radSource4 button is clicked and "txtQuiaLink" and "txtQuiaPass" when the radSource5 button is clicked.  How do I go about doing that... I am a little new to Google Apps Script and trying to learn some basics.  Thanks

```
    //Create the GUI form

function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('DHS: Kurzweil Calendar');

  //Create a panel which holds all the form elelemnts
  var vertMainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('vertMainPanel');

  //Create the form elelemnts
  var lblTeacherName = app.createLabel('Teacher Name:');
  var txtTeacherName = app.createTextBox().setName('txtTeacherName');

  var lblExt = app.createLabel('Ext:');
  var txtExt = app.createTextBox().setName('txtExt');

  var lblDate = app.createLabel('Date:');
  var boxDate = app.createDateBox().setId('boxDate').setName('boxDate').setFormat(UiApp.DateTimeFormat.DATE_SHORT);

  var lbxSubject = app.createListBox().setId('lbxSubject').setName('lbxSubject');
  var lstSubjItems = ['-- Select One --','Algebra I (OCS)','Algebra II','Algebra II (Honors)','Agriscience Applications','Agriscience Applications (OCS)','Anatomy and Physiology','Anatomy and Physiology (Honors)','Animal Science','American Sign Language II','Apparel I','Art History (AP)','Advanced Functions and Modeling','Automotive Computer System Diagnostics','Automotive Brakes','Automotive Service','Automotive Service (OCS)', 'Benchmarks','Bible History','Biology','Biology (AP)','Biology (Honors)','Biology (OCS)','Biomedical Technology','Biotechnology and Agriscience','Calculus AB (AP)','Calculus BC (AP)','Carpentry I','Carpentry I (OCS)','Carpentry III','Chemistry','Chemistry (AP)','Chemistry (Honors)','Choral Arts (Beginning)','Civics and Economics','Civics and Economics (Honors)','Computer Programming I','Computer Science (AP)','Computer Technology','Concert Band II (Beginning)',        'Concert Band II (Proficient)','Core and Sustainable Construction','Core and Sustainable Construction (OCS)','Digital Media I','Digitial Media I (OCS)','Digital Media II','Discrete Mathematics','Drafting I','Drafting Architecture II (Honors)','Drafting Architecture III (Honors)','Earth and Environmental Science','Earth and Environmental Sceince (AP)','Earth and Environmental Science (Honors)','Early Childhood Ed I','eCommerce I (Honors)','English I','English I (Honors)','English II','English II (Honors)','English II (OCS)','English III','English III (Honors)','English III (OCS)','English IV','English IV (Honors)','English IV (OCS)','English Lang and Comp (AP)','English Language Arts II','English Language Arts III','Engish Literature (AP)','European History (AP)','Fashion Merchandising','Financial Management (OCS)','Foods I','Foods I (OCS)','Foods II - Enterprise','Foods II - Advanced (OCS)','French I','French II','French III (Honors)','Functional Finances','Geometry', 'Geometry (Honors)','German I','German II','German III (Honors)','Health and Physical Education','Health Sciences (Advanced Studies)','Health Team Relations','Human Geography (AP)','Holocaust and Peace Studies','Horticulture I','Horticulture I (OCS)','Horticulture II','Horticulture II (OCS)','Integrated Math I','Interior Design I','Introduction to Math','Japanese I','JROTC I','JROTC II','JROTC III','JROTC IV','Latin I','Latim II','Latin III (Honors)','Leadership Development','Marketing Management','Masonry I','Masonry I (OCS)','Masonry III','Microsoft Excel and Access','Microsoft Word PowerPoint and Publisher','Multimedia and Webpage Design','Music Business and Recording (Beginning)','Occupational Preparations I','Occupational Preparations II','Occupational Preparations III','Occupational Preparations IV','Parent and Child Development',        'Parent and Child Development (OCS)','Personal Finance',        'Personal Finance (OCS)','Physical Science','Physics (Honors)','Pre-Calculus (Honors)','Professional Management and Leadership I','Professional Management and Leadership II','Psychology','Physcology (AP)','Psychology (Honors)','SAT Preparation','Science and Technical Visualization I','Science and Technical Visualization II','Social Studies (OCS)','Spanish I','Spanish II','Spanish III (Honors)','Spanish IV (Honors)','Special Topics of Mathematics','Symphonic Band II (Beginning)','Symphonic Band II (Intermediate)','Symphonic Band II (Proficient)','Technology Engineering and Design','Theatre Arts (Beginning)','Theatre Arts (Intermediate)','US History','US History (AP)','US History (Honors)','Visual Arts (Beginning)','Visual Arts (Intermediate)','Visual Arts (Proficient)','Visual Arts (Advanced)','Visual Arts Specialization in Ceramics (Advanced)','Vocal Ensemble (Intermediate)','Vocal Ensemble (Proficient)','Wind Ensemble II (Intermediate)','Wind Ensemble II (Proficient)','Wind Ensemble II (Advanced)','World Geography','World History','World History','World History (Honors)'];
      lstSubjItems.sort();

      for (var l = 0; l < lstSubjItems.length; l++) {
        lbxSubject.addItem(lstSubjItems[l]);
      }

  var lbxPeriod = app.createListBox().setId('lbxPeriod').setName('lbxPeriod');
  var lstPrdItems = ['-- Select One --','1st Period','2nd Period','3rd Period','4th Period'];
      lstPrdItems.sort();

      for (var l = 0; l < lstPrdItems.length; l++) {
        lbxPeriod.addItem(lstPrdItems[l]);
      }

  var lblStudentNum = app.createLabel('Number of Students:');
  var txtStudentNum = app.createTextBox().setName('txtStudentNum');

  var txtRadioGrp1 = app.createTextBox().setName('txtRadioGrp1').setVisible(false);
  var txtRadioGrp2 = app.createTextBox().setName('txtRadioGrp2').setVisible(false);
  var txtElementsID = app.createTextBox().setName('txtElementsID').setVisible(false);
  var txtQuiaLink = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaLink').setVisible(false);
  var txtQuiaPass = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaPass').setVisible(false);
  //Create Source Radio Button Group
  var radSource1 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Hard-Copy').setFormValue('Hard-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp1).setText('Hard-Copy'));
  var radSource2 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Electronic-Copy').setFormValue('Electronic-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp1).setText('Electronic-Copy'));
  //Create Type Radio Button Group
  var radSource3 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Teacher-Made Exam').setFormValue('Teacher-Made Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp2).setText('Teacher-Made Exam'));
  var radSource4 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Elements Exam').setFormValue('Elements Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp1).setText('Elements Exam'));
      if (radSource4 == true) {
          txtElementsID.setVisible(true);
      } else {
          txtElementsID.setVisible(false);
      }
  var radSource5 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Quia Exam').setFormValue('Quia Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp1).setText('Quia Exam'));
      if (radSource5 == true) {
          txtQuiaLink.setVisible(true);
          txtQuiaPass.setVisible(true);
      }  else {
          txtQuiaLink.setVisible(false);
          txtQuiaPass.setVisible(false);
      }
  var btnCreate = app.createButton('Create Event');

  //Create handler which will execute 'createEvents(e)' on clicking the button
  var evtHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('createEvents');
      evtHandler.addCallbackElement(vertMainPanel);
  //Add this handler to the button
      btnCreate.addClickHandler(evtHandler);

  //Add all the elemnts to the panel 
  vertMainPanel.add(lblTeacherName)
       .add(txtTeacherName)
       .add(lblExt)
       .add(txtExt)
       .add(lblDate)
       .add(boxDate)
       .add(lbxSubject)
       .add(lbxPeriod)
       .add(lblStudentNum)
       .add(txtStudentNum)
       .add(radSource1)
       .add(radSource2)
       .add(txtRadioGrp1)
       .add(radSource3)
       .add(radSource4)
       .add(txtElementsID)
       .add(radSource5)
       .add(txtQuiaLink)
       .add(txtQuiaPass)
       .add(txtRadioGrp2)
       .add(btnCreate)

  //Add this panel to the application
  app.add(vertMainPanel);

  //Return the application
  return app;
}

function createEvents(e){

  //Get the active application
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  try{
    //Get the entries
    var ssTeacher = e.parameter.txtTeacherName;
    var ssExt = e.parameter.txtExt;
    var ssSubject = e.parameter.lbxSubject;
    var ssPeriod = e.parameter.lbxPeriod;
    var ssStudentNum = e.parameter.txtStudentNum;
    var ssSource = e.parameter.txtRadioGrp1;
    var ssType = e.parameter.txtRadioGrp2;
    var eventDate = e.parameter.boxDate;
    var eventCalSubject = ssPeriod + ": " + ssTeacher + " (" + ssStudentNum + ")";
    var eventCalDetails = "Extension: " + ssExt + "\n" +
          "Subject: " + ssSubject + "\n\n" +
          "Source: " + ssSource + "\n" +
          "Type: " + ssType + "\n";

    //Get the calendar
    var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('davie.k12.nc.us_d2mv2eb8aspuant1vb5j6r3sis@group.calendar.google.com');//Change the calendar id
    //Create the events
    cal.createAllDayEvent(eventCalSubject, eventDate, {description:eventCalDetails});

    //Log the entries in a spreadsheet
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Aur3owCpuUY-dGJIOGZ1LXhqT2FNMGVXSGNJazFnUmc#gid=0').getActiveSheet();//Change the spreadhseet key to yours
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var targetRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues([[new Date(),eventDate,ssTeacher,ssExt,ssSubject,ssPeriod,ssSource,ssType,ssStudentNum,'Event created']]);
    return app;

    //Show the confirmation message
    app.add(app.createLabel('Kurzweil Calendar Event created successfully...'));
    //Make the form panel invisible
    app.getElementById('vertMainPanel').setVisible(false);
    return app;
  }

  //If an error occurs, show it on the panel
  catch(e){
    app.add(app.createLabel('Error occured: '+ e));
    return app;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need these textBoxes to hide when another radioButton is clicked or should they stay visible ?

Comment: Hide when another radioButton is clicked...

Comment: **Off Topic:** Are there any good resources out there for learning Google App Script? I have only found one very poorly written book and the Google Developer Site, which seems all over the place. Where would be a good starting point?  Thanks

Comment: Google Apps Script is javascript with a few extensions related to Google services... reading the documentation and answering/reading this forum has been the only resource that I needed.  Among the 4293 questions with GAS tag on SO, many are really interesting and the search engine will help to find what you're interrested in.  Well, at least it does for me ;-)  There are also a lot of blogs and personal sites that provide code example but I found it often either over-complicated or simplistic :-/ the Google+ community might also be interresting sometimes but it's not my cup of tea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ClientHandlers that toggle visibility...

A short example is better than a long explanation, I guess it's clear enough, just insert the following code after you have created all the radioButtons and textBoxes.

[DEMO app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw8-6yO9HzrgZvWEOg9phl-gzTo60x2LvpvdCdjrOYTkUSFhcs/exec)  and full code [here](http://pastebin.com/NzUJ0R0X)

```
  //Client Handlers for textBoxes
  var showTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsID).setVisible(true);
  var hideTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsID).setVisible(false);
  radSource4.addClickHandler(showTxtElementHandler);// show when click on radio4
  radSource3.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);// hide if click other
  radSource5.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);

  var showtxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(true);
  var hidetxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(false);
  radSource5.addClickHandler(showtxtQuiaLinkHandler);// show when clicked on radio5
  radSource3.addClickHandler(hidetxtQuiaLinkHandler);// hide in other cases
  radSource4.addClickHandler(hidetxtQuiaLinkHandler);
```

---

**EDIT :** did you mean something like this ? :

[image]

in this case I did it with an horizontal panel like below (demo updated)

```
  var txtRadioGrp1 = app.createTextBox().setName('txtRadioGrp1').setVisible(false);
  var txtRadioGrp2 = app.createTextBox().setName('txtRadioGrp2').setVisible(false);
  var txtElementsID = app.createTextBox().setName('txtElementsID');
  var txtQuiaLink = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaLink');
  var txtElementsIDP = app.createHorizontalPanel().add(app.createLabel('enter a value')).add(txtElementsID).setVisible(false);
  var txtQuiaLinkP = app.createHorizontalPanel().add(app.createLabel('enter a value')).add(txtQuiaLink).setVisible(false);
  var txtQuiaPass = app.createTextBox().setName('txtQuiaPass').setVisible(false);
  //Create Source Radio Button Group
  var radSource1 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Hard-Copy').setFormValue('Hard-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp1).setText('Hard-Copy'));
  var radSource2 = app.createRadioButton('group1', 'Electronic-Copy').setFormValue('Electronic-Copy').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp1).setText('Electronic-Copy'));
  //Create Type Radio Button Group
  var radSource3 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Teacher-Made Exam').setFormValue('Teacher-Made Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp2).setText('Teacher-Made Exam'));
  var radSource4 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Elements Exam').setFormValue('Elements Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp1).setText('Elements Exam'));
  var radSource5 = app.createRadioButton('group2', 'Quia Exam').setFormValue('Quia Exam').addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtRadioGrp1).setText('Quia Exam'));

  var btnCreate = app.createButton('Create Event');

  //Client Handlers for textBoxes
  var showTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsIDP).setVisible(true);
  var hideTxtElementHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtElementsIDP).setVisible(false);
  radSource4.addClickHandler(showTxtElementHandler);
  radSource3.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);
  radSource5.addClickHandler(hideTxtElementHandler);

  var showtxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLinkP).setVisible(true);
  var hidetxtQuiaLinkHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(txtQuiaLinkP).setVisible(false);
  radSource5.addClickHandler(showtxtQuiaLinkHandler);
  radSource3.addClickHandler(hidetxtQuiaLinkHandler);
  radSource4.addClickHandler(hidetxtQuiaLinkHandler);
```

---

EDIT 2 : GRID version

[image]

```
  //Add all the elemnts to the panel 
  var grid = app.createGrid(12,2).setCellPadding(5);
  vertMainPanel.add(grid);
  grid.setWidget(0,0,lblTeacherName)
  .setWidget(0,1,txtTeacherName)
  .setWidget(1,0,lblExt)
  .setWidget(1,1,txtExt)
  .setWidget(2,0,lblDate)
  .setWidget(2,1,boxDate)
  .setWidget(3,1,lbxSubject)
  .setWidget(3,0,lbxPeriod)
  .setWidget(4,0,lblStudentNum)
  .setWidget(4,1,txtStudentNum)
  .setWidget(5,0,radSource1)
  .setWidget(5,1,radSource2)
  .setWidget(6,0,txtRadioGrp1)
  .setWidget(7,0,radSource3)
  .setWidget(8,0,radSource4)
  .setWidget(8,1,txtElementsIDP)
  .setWidget(9,0,radSource5)
  .setWidget(9,1,txtQuiaLinkP)
  .setWidget(10,0,txtQuiaPass)
  .setWidget(10,1,txtRadioGrp2)
  .setWidget(11,0,btnCreate);
```

Comment: That works beautifully... however, how can I add a "label" to the fields... it won't work the same way as the textboxes because there is no way to reference the field by name.

Comment: What do you mean by 'fields'.?

Comment: Thinking... Do you mean you'd like a label to appear aside of the textBox on its left for example ?

Comment: Looking at your UI I'd suggest you try the grid widget to position your different items, it would probably look nicer...

Comment: Here is a test with a grid : not bad isn't it ? full code is on my pasteBin, see ref in answer   https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwtjoXhE4-H3SZYNNcHY43TVf1lcILHKiGkfqH5UVngM0X5JRc/exec

Comment: added a preset value to the radioButtons - including on grid demo app

Comment: Thanks...yes, exactly. I am really learning a lot over the last couple post on how to think through creating what I want. Thanks for all your help and I think I will modify everything into the GRID 2 option. It looks really good that way, more like a form.

Comment: well, glad to help :-) please think about accepting the answer.

Comment: I edited the pasteBin with a couple of labels in the grid itself (grid.setText(row,col,'label string'))